# How do I reset microphone permissions on Catalina?

Tags: catalina, audio, permission, microphone

I know there is an article covering this for MacOS Mojave, but as I am trying to grant an application (Plogue Bidule) permission to access the "microphone" and with this all audio input but do not receive the prompt that allows me to do this on MacOS Catalina, I rephrase the question for Catalina.
Thanks for any hints.